# Height в % Opera,Explorer,Firefox

Tags: html, css, height

В Opera, Explorer и Firefox `height`, заданный в процентах, не воспринимается!

Что делать, если необходимо задать высоту в процентах?

Сайт с проблемой: https://invest-apartments.ru.

Comment: Печально. И что будем с этим делать?

Comment: Либо вычислять нужную высоту с помощью JavaScript.

Comment: Deonis,опера не воспринимает высоту в процентах!

Comment: http://invest-apartments.ru/ -мой сайт.
Проблема  Explorer,Opera,Firefox.
Высота верхнего и нижнего блока равная 50% от экрана,не работает в вышеперечисленных браузерах.

Comment: Вот не надо кидать ссылку на сайт, нужно привести в тексте вопроса КОД. Минимально необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы.

Comment: Стараюсь вообще не применять проценты к высоте, если прям дико надо, то есть один хак: `.example {position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; height: 50%;}`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы высота работала в Explorer, Opera и Firefox необходимо всем блокам, в которые обернут ваш блок, прописать значение высоты `100%`. И у `body` попробуйте прописать высоту `100%`.

И, кстати, чтобы не было белых отступов по краям страницы у `body` укажите еще атрибуты `margin:0; padding: 0;`

Answer (score 1):

1. Найди в вашем html закрывающий тег </center>. Его там нет.
2. Да и вообще, использовать этот тег, практически, как вторую по важности "обёртку" - это что-то. Кстати, в html5 он достойно забыт.
3. У вас есть хорошие помощники - это валидаторы: как [html](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Finvest-apartments.ru%2F), так и [css](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css21&warning=0&uri=http%3A%2F%2Finvest-apartments.ru%2F)

Из всего увиденного, напрашивается вывод, что вы только начали делать первые шаги в этом направлении. Пройдите для начала [основы по html](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml) и [css](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss).

Answer (score 0):

Задавайте высоту в `vh` (viewport height) — единицах задающих высоту в процентах высоты экрана.

Чтобы ваш блок занимал 50% высоты экрана установите ему `height: 50vh;`.